# What is a cluster and a node oriented to containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

Sorry for this question, but I just started with **Docker and Docker Compose** and I really didn't need any of this until I read that I need to use **Docker Swarn or Kuebernetes** to have more stability in production. I started reading about Docker Swarn and they mentioned nodes and clusters.

I was really happy not knowing about this as I understood `docker-compose`:

> Is that I could manage my **services/containers** from a single file
>   and only have to run several commands to launch, build, delete, etc.
>   all my services based on the docker-compose configuration.

But now the **nodes and cluster** have come out and I've really gone a bit crazy, and that's why if you can help me understand this next step in the life of containers. I've been googling and it's not very clear to me.

I hope you can help me and explain it to me in a way that I can understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A **node** is just a physical or virtual machine.
In Kubernetes/Docker Swarm context each node must have the relevant binaries installed (Docker Engine, kubelet etc..)

A **cluster** is a grouping of one or more nodes.

If you have just been testing on your local machine you have a single **node**.

If you were to add a second machine and link both machines together using **docker swarm/kubernetes** then you would have created a **2 node cluster**

You can then use **docker swarm/kubernetes** to run your **services/containers** on any or all **nodes** in your **cluster**. This allows your services to be more resilient and fault tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

By default Docker Compose runs a set of containers on a single system.  If you need to run more containers than fit on one system, or you're just afraid of that system crashing, you need more than one system to do it.  The **cluster** is the group of all of the systems (physical computers, virtual machines, cloud instances) that are working together to run the containers.  Each of those individual systems is a **node**.

The other important part of the cluster container setups is that you can generally run multiple *replicas* of a give container, and you don't care where in the cluster they run.  Say you have five nodes, and a Web server container, and you'd like to run three copies of it for redundancy.  Instead of having to pick a node, ssh to it, and manually `docker run` there, you just tell the cluster manager "run me three of these", and it chooses a node and launches the container for you.  You can also scale the containers up and down at runtime, or potentially set the cluster to do the scaling on its own based on load.

If your workload is okay running a single copy of containers on a single server, you don't need a cluster setup.  (You might have some downtime during updates or if the single server dies.)  Swarm has the advantages of being bundled with Docker and being able to use Docker-native tools (`docker-compose` can deploy to a Swarm cluster).  Kubernetes is much more complex, but at this point most public cloud providers will sell you a preconfigured Kubernetes cluster, and it has better stories around security, storage management, and autoscaling.  There are also a couple other less-prominent alternatives like Nomad and Mesos out there.

Comment: Thanks very much. How can I know or calculate the containers that fit in a single system or node? Only by disk space and memory? I'm saying this because I just uploaded a VPS with 5 container with Docker-compose, and it's going really well. It only uses 19% of the disk space and 22% of the memory.

Comment: Excuse me and to understand everything well, when you mean "You might have some downtime during updates" you mean when I might upload new changes to my files to the **web container***, right now I had to do several and I did it by copying files from the host to the container in the early morning so no one would suffer any cuts. More or less the old-fashioned way. But really with the taste of being able to use docker-compose.

Comment: In a Docker world you wouldn't generally upload files to the container directly, you'd build a new image that contained the new version.  In a non-cluster environment you have to stop the old container and build a new one.  If you have three replicas in a cluster environment, you can upgrade those one at a time without interrupting service.

Comment: Thanks so much. You can answer the first question in the comments.